# Attach extended properties to a stored procedure result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I'm trying to attach metadata to the result set of a stored procedure. The procedure would return a table, either as the result of a SELECT query, or a temporary table built in the procedure itself. I'd like to decorate its columns with additional information, to sort of emulate .NET's attributes. Then, when executing the procedure with `ADO.NET`, I want to evaluate this metadata.

As far as I can tell, this can't easily be done. I could perhaps work around it by creating a global temporary table (`##` prefix), then manually attaching extended properties to it in `tempdb`. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can tell that can not be done at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not return 2 result sets from the SP? One is the actual result set, the one you have now and the other one is the metadata.

The metadata table can be a table variable created in the SP, with this structure:

```
DECLARE @ResultsMetadata AS TABLE
(
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  ColumnName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  ColumnMetadata VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
```

The you can read this in what I assume is a CLR (because of the tag). It's easy to read multiple result sets with an `SqlDataReader`. If you need to process the results further also in SQL, then perhaps you can switch to an XML output with two top level elements (main result set and meta data).

**EDIT**

Actually just noticed that you're reading this with ADO.NET, so you shouldn't have any problems with multiple result sets. You can use [`SqlDataReader.NextResult`](https://www.google.ro/search?q=NextResult&oq=NextResult&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) to advance the reader to the second (metadata) result set.

Comment: Yep, that's a hack I did have in mind, but wanted to avoid. I'll probably go with that, thanks.

Comment: @SörenKuklau: Yes :), I think it can be called a hack when looking at it this way. However, when you want to eliminate some roundtrips it's actually perfect.

Answer (score 3):

**Suggested Method 1:**

create Metadata type in first:

```
CREATE TYPE MetaData AS TABLE
(
  Name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  Property NVARCHAR(Max)
)
```

In each stored procedure return your metadata after result set of your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedure 
AS BEGIN
    --FIRST Result Set
    --Your Stored Procedure code here
    ...


    --Second Result Set
    DECLARE @MetaData dbo.MetaData 
    INSERT INTO @MetaData(Name, Property)VALUES(...)
    SELECT * FROM @MetaData
END
```

You can read your result set in code separately. following code is a C# code in order to get multi result set from one stored procedure.

```
SqlConnection oConn = null;
DataSet dsReturn = null;
try
{
    getConnection(ref oConn, 1);

    using (SqlStoredProcedure sspObj = new SqlStoredProcedure("dbo.YourStoredProcedure", oConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        sspObj.AddParameterWithValue("@Parameter", SqlDbType.Int, Parametervalue, ParameterDirection.Input, type);
        dsReturn = sspObj.ExecuteDataSet();
        //You don't need Dispose() - because the using will do that on sspObj
    }

    closeConnection(ref oConn);
}
catch (Exception xObj)
{
    dsReturn = new DataSet("Empty");
}
```

In above code `dsReturn.Tables[0]` is result set of your stored procedure and  `dsReturn.Tables[1]` is result set of metadata of your stored procedure.

**Suggested Method 2:**

Add each metadata that want to extended property of your stored procedure:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MetaDataColumn1', @value=N'value1' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'YourProcedure'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MetaDataColumn2', @value=N'value2' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'YourProcedure'
GO
```

Following query, return metadata of your stored procedure:

```
SELECT ep.name, ep.value
FROM sys.extended_properties ep
INNER JOIN sys.procedures p ON p.object_id = ep.major_id
WHERE p.name = 'YourProcedure'
    AND ep.name LIKE 'MetaData%'
```

you can execute above query from your code (C# sample):

```
connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
sql = "AboveQuery";
sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
sqlCnn.Open();
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn);
SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```